# Seria possível num futuro a lingua Portuguesa adotar sinais de pergunta no começo da frase?

Tags: ortografia, pontuação

Será que para o idioma Português seria viável um dia adotar o sinal de pergunta no começo da frase?
Já se cogitou em alguma época?

Comment: Danilo, boa noite e seja bem-vindo ao site.  Infelizmente qualquer resposta à sua pergunta seria a opinião de quem responde, e não uma resposta que pode ser confirmada com referências.  Esse tipo de pergunta foge aos objetivos do site.  Mas sinta-se a vontade a fazer perguntas cujas respostas não sejam baseadas em opiniões pessoais.

Comment: @Centaurus, o post tem 2 perguntas e acho que ambas são válidas. Os espanhois usam o duplo ponto de interrogação invertido no princípio e final da frase, no universo da linguística portuguesa já se terá comentado e ponderado sobre a possibilidade de adoptar essa norma de pontuação. (É uma questão de encontrar referências na literatura.)